# How to avoid loading Spring context for every change?

Tags: java, spring, playframework

I'm working on a new project with Play Framework (which I'm still learning). One problem that I noticed is that for every change, Spring context needs to be reloaded, which takes 10s on average. Is this normal? I'm used to working with Django and there I was able to see the changes really fast in my application. Is there a way to improve this loading time of Spring?

Answer (score 0):

10 Seconds are normal for a medium sized application.

You could use [JRebel](http://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/) to update you application on the fly.

Comment: Hi Ralph, actually is taking 30s to reload everything.. is this really normal? And thanks for the suggestion I will take a look into `JRebel` for sure!

Comment: My medium sized spring applications need 15 to 17 seconds to startup. But they do NOT have heavy initialization stuff to do. - What I know, is that intensive logging need a lot of time while startup, that is way I mostly used logglevel INFO for Spring Libs and Hibernate, so my startup log output is about 300 lines (85k).

Comment: But, while you're developing, save the changes, it takes 15-17 seconds to load spring contexts again ? This is what is happening with me. I feel that I'm wasting so much time just to see a simple change, you know ?

Comment: Depends how you develop. I (re)start my spring application only 1 to 10 times per day. The rest of the day I develop the application using testcases. - Of curse when I develop frontendstuff, mostly jsp, then I do not need to restart the server, because jsp changes are taken in account without restarting Tomcat.